# Oracle 19c TDE syskm

Tags: tde, ora-01017, oracle19c

db version is 19.3.

While deploying TDE in PDB, we are unable to connect to the PDB as syskm. We are able to connect to the PDB as sys user without errors.

```
SQL> connect syskm@USA_DEV as syskm
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
Warning: You are no longer connected to ORACLE.

SQL> connect sys@usa_dev as sysdba
Connected.

SQL> connect c##abc@usa_dev
Connected.
```

There is no issues reported in Metalink for syskm.
Any know issues with syskm for 19c PDB? OR any ideas?

Comment: Well, did you create that `syskm` user?

Comment: No, it was already there in CDB. It is a common user. Just changed the password to my liking.

Answer (score 0):

Used the SYS user to perform the TDE key and keystore setup in PDBs instead of SYSKM user. This falls into workaround for us but it works.